# wildcard in scripts

Tags: bash, scripting

It is fine to run

```
 evince ./result/demo_1000000_10000*.ps
```

on a shell window. But when I put it into a scripts file, then run that file, it can not find all those files ./result/demo_1000000_10000*.ps... here * is meant to be a wildcard and following is the scripts.

```
evince ./result/demo_1000000_10000"*.ps"
```

So are there any changes that should be made when putting commands into scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work the same way in a script or on the command line.  The quotation marks prevent the wildcard from being expanded.  Just remove them from the script.  (Why did you add them in the first place?)

Answer (score 0):

If the command runs from the prompt as shown, then it should also run from a shell script if the current directory of the invoking process is the same - with exactly the same notation.  There is no reason to include quotes in the scripted version if you want it to do the same as the unscripted version.  And if you ran the quoted version at the command line, it would fail the same as the quoted version in the scripted version does.

However, in a script, you do have to worry about whether the Postscript files you plan to work on are in the correct location.  Sometimes, the script uses an absolute pathname, sometimes the script uses `cd` to change directory to the correct place, sometimes there's an argument or environment variable that locates the files.

So, if used carefully, you don't have to change anything for the script to work - but there are many ways you can prevent the script from working.  One of those is by adding quotes around wildcard characters.